# Powershell V2 find and replace

Tags: powershell, replace

I am trying to change dates programmatically in a file. The line I need to fix looks like this:

```
    set @@dateto = '03/15/12'
```

I need to write a powershell V2 script that replaces what's inside the single quotes, and I have no idea how to do this.

The closest I've come looks like this:

```
    gc $file | ? {$_ -match "set @@dateto ="} | % {$temp=$_.split("'");$temp[17] 
     =$CorrectedDate;$temp -join ","} | -outfile newfile.txt
```

Problems with this: It gives an error about the index 17 being out of range. Also, the outfile only contains one line (The unmodified line). I'd appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this ( though you may want to handle the corner cases) :

```
$CorrectedDate = '10/09/09'
gc $file | %{ 
    if($_ -match "^set @@dateto = '(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d)'") { 
        $_ -replace $matches[1], $CorrectedDate; 
    }  
    else {
        $_
    } 
} | out-file test2.txt
mv test2.txt $file -force
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response- Just having one problem with it- It is not changing in the outfile. I'm just getting a copy of $file (I skipped the mv line for now) Let me know what I need to correct. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Found the problem- it was on me. I had the date in there as 1/5/13, so the date pattern it should have been matching was \d/\d/\d\d. I went and prepended 0's to the two numbers, it works like a charm. Thanks!